# WPF design pattern for "automated" applications (Don't think MVVM is suitable?)

Tags: wpf, design-patterns

I'm trying to get into WPF and have been reading articles saying MVVM is generally the way to go for WPF.

What about application that doesn't require user interactions such as button clicks?

An example would be a Card reader application:

- User connect card.
- Application read and display card info on screen.
- Perform backend validation.
- Display result on screen.

I could be wrong but I don't see MVVM being suitable for such application. Is there a more suitable design pattern that I should be considering instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of MVVM is to detach your views from your code.
Lets say in a month you need another view, you can easily create one without having to worry about "logic" being part of the view.
Mind you, some things are still easier done in the code behind ... but depending on your "purist" status, it'll vary.

Having said that, you can still happily use MVVM for your card application, and use the GUI to switch around and show different views ...

Last thing is I'll recommend picking an MVVM framework to help you jump start. There's plenty of them out there, varying in complexity and goals.

MvvmLight , Castel (?), Prism, Micro mvvm (?) ... run a quick search and see which you like .

Having said the above, let me shamelessly plug this article: [The big mvvm template](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/768427/The-big-MVVM-Template)

Comment: Thanks for your input! And sorry for the late response. I've decided to start with MVVM Light. :)

Comment: no worries. glad i could help. (i like that one two btw. the author seems like a great guy as well)